# Package look and feel dependency into executable jar with maven

Tags: java, swing, maven, netbeans, look-and-feel

I am using Substance Look and Feel for my Swing GUI application with Netbeans and Maven.

When I run the project from within Netbeans, the Look and Feel is applied, but when I clean and build the project and execute the jar produced by maven, the GUI reverts to the default look and feel.

Also, while inspecting the produced jar, I dont see the substance files anywhere.

I have added the substance dependency through maven and even tried changing it scope to runtime, but there was no change. I encounter no errors or exceptions while compiling or executing the program. What is the problem?

I am using JDK 7 on a 64 bit Windows 8 machine.

Here is the code for setting the LaF:

```
try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("org.pushingpixels.substance.api.skin.SubstanceGraphiteLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Texus.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

And here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pawandubey</groupId>
    <artifactId>Texus</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-ALPHA</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.pawandubey.texus.Texus</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.insubstantial</groupId>
            <artifactId>substance</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.seaglasslookandfeel</groupId>
            <artifactId>seaglasslookandfeel</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: It would be beneficial for me if people explain their downvotes as well.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide some saples of code, so other people can see what you are doing and provide the answers you seek.

Comment: I provided the relevant parts. I dont see what is the problem with the code since it works fine inside the IDE.

Comment: (By the way, I didn't downvoted your question ;) )

Comment: @Barranka Well that is too bad, since that means nobody who downvoted has bothered to explain :)

Comment: You should provide for people the command line execution, complete with your classpath that you used to run your application.  

The maven jar plugin does not bundle the substance jar into a single executable jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [QuickStartJavaMavenProject](http://wiki.netbeans.org/QuickStartJavaMavenProject). It explains you should use the [maven-assemply-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to create a jar with your dependencies. Something like

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
       <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
       </descriptorRefs>
       <archive>
          <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.areaofthoughts.grumpycat.GrumpyCat</mainClass>
          </manifest>
       </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>                        
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Substance look and feel is most likely missing from your classpath.